# what is the statistical risk of head rotor failure?

Tags: security, rotorcraft, aircraft-failure, rotor-head

What are the chances of rotor failure? What percentage of crashes are related to a malfunction of the rotor head?

Comment: You are welcome to search the [NTSB Accident Database](http://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx) for helicopter accidents with certain keywords. I'm not sure that this is answerable though as the data isn't typically compiled as percentages due to a certain component failure. I'm willing to say though that rotor head failure is insignificant given accident reports I've read.

Comment: I've only ever heard of 2, which doesn't of course mean that they are more, but I would say statistically insignificant.  In my experience, the great majority of rotor failures has been the result of something else, e.g. not entering autorotation quickly enough after an engine failure; mishandlng negative G in a helicopter with a semi-rigid head etc.

Answer (score 2):

I worked medium and heavy transport helos in the Marines, and I never heard of an incident caused by a rotor head failure. Blades, transmissions, all kinds of other things, sure, but not main rotor heads.